# Python creating files

Tags: python

```
while True:
    rand = random.randint(70, 123)
    randomer = random.randint(70, 123)
    c = chr(randomer)
    f = chr(rand)
    f = f
    path = os.path.join(r'D:\Python\New folder', f)
    secondPath = os.path.join(r'D:\Python\New folder', f+c)
    thirdPath = os.path.join(r'D:\Python\New folder', f+c+'INTERWABZ.CC')
#'.exe'
    if '\\' in f :
        continue

    elif '\\' in c:
        continue
    open(f, 'w')


    if os.path.exists(path):
        open(f+c, 'w')
    elif os.path.exists(secondPath):
        open(f+c+'INTERWABZ.CC', 'a')
    elif os.path.exists(thirdPath):
        open(f+c+'.exe', 'a')
```

This code is supposed to create files with all possible characters of f, then when all those characters are used to create a file, a second character (c) is supposed to be added to the first character (f) then create a file with that name. This program only seems to only create files with two letters...

Comment: Please read - How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Aside the simple fact that the code never check for terminating (so it run forever) and that there are far better ways to do the job (permutations), the block

```
if os.path.exists(path):
    open(f+c, 'w')
elif os.path.exists(secondPath):
    open(f+c+'INTERWABZ.CC', 'a')
elif os.path.exists(thirdPath):
    open(f+c+'.exe', 'a')
```

seems to be wrong on at least 2 counts:

1. you are testing if a path exist and the you try (in teory) to create another path
2. `os.path.exists(path)` return false (the first time) since the file does not exist and then it not create the file, since you are trying to create the file only if it already exist.

So a little more corrected code can be:

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
    open(path, 'w')
elif not os.path.exists(secondPath):
    open(secondPath, 'a')
elif not os.path.exists(thirdPath):
    open(thirdPath, 'a')
```

which created all the files, but still has the problem the the `while` never ends.